# How do I embed a hyperlink in a NewForm.aspx to a second related list

Tags: jquery, related-list

I have two related lists in SharePoint 2013. I want to add a link from the new form of one list (NewForm.aspx) to open the second list, so I would be able to add new items to the second list quickly. Is there a quick way to achieve this without much code? maybe using some jquery or something similar?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Edit the newform.aspx page of the list. Add content editor webpart to the page. Place the anchor tag with url of another list's newform.aspx. However, you can also use SharePoint modal dialog framework.

```
//Using the DialogOptions class.
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();

options.title = "My Dialog Title";
options.width = 400;
options.height = 600;
options.url = "/ListName/NewForm.aspx";

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);

//Using a generic object.
var options = {
    title: "My Dialog Title",
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    url: "/ListName/NewForm.aspx" };

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Comment: Hi Nadeem, Thank you for your respond. The solution suggested is opening a popup with the NewForm.aspx of the child list right away and it is great however I was aiming to add an hyperlink to the child NewForm.aspx (if possible within the parent NewForm.aspx). Do you happen to know if there is a way to achieve this?